# how to sort products by price In App Purchases?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

First,I got some products from IAP

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response  
{  
    [productDetailsList addObjectsFromArray: response.products];  
    [productDisplayTableView reloadData];  
}
```

How to put them in a uitableview sort by product price? thank you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{  
    static NSString *GenericTableIdentifier = @"GenericTableIdentifier";  
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: GenericTableIdentifier];  
    if (cell == nil) {  
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier:GenericTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }   

    SKProduct *thisProduct = [productDetailsList objectAtIndex:row];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    [button setTitle:localizedMoneyString forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    return cell; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is sort the NSArray prior to trying to read it. There are many options for sorting NSArray, most of them involve creating your own sorting method. You do something like:

```
[productDetailList sortedArrayUsingFunction:intSort context:NULL];
```

That will use your comparator method that you specify. The comparison method is used to compare two elements at a time and should return NSOrderedAscending if the first element is smaller than the second, NSOrderedDescending if the first element is larger than the second, and NSOrderedSame if the elements are equal. Each time the comparison function is called, it’s passed context as its third argument. This allows the comparison to be based on some outside parameter, such as whether character sorting is case-sensitive or case-insensitive, but this doesn't matter in your case. The function you have to implement would look like this:

```
NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
```

For more information of the above method take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), it give you an example.

So you can sort the array like this or you always have the choice of sorting the array every time you add something. So every time you add an object you do the sorting yourself and make sure to put it in the right location to keep the array always sorted.

Depending on what you want, I would say keeping the array constantly sorted on insertion time is the best option, so you don't have to waste time while building the view by sorting the array. To do it like this would be simple, every time you enter something into the array, you iterate through the array until you find an object with a price larger than the one you want to enter, then you insert the object at the location before that entry.

Comment: Hi,I got a error reason: '-[SKProduct compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2e2ee0'

Comment: Inside your SKProduct did you implement the compare function that would do the above? `compare(id arg1, id arg2, void *context)`? Return NSOrderedAscending if arg1 < arg2, return NSOrderedDescending if arg1 > arg2, and return NSOrderedSame if arg1 == arg2. Once you implement that function in SKProduct you can call `[productDetailList sortedArrayUsingFunction:compare context:NULL];` and should work, if not please post more results and/or your code.

Answer (score 14):

```
NSArray *products = [response.products sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
        NSDecimalNumber *first = [(SKProduct*)a price];
        NSDecimalNumber *second = [(SKProduct*)b price];
        return [first compare:second];
    }];
```

Comment: Great solution, just what the OP needed.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 2.1.1

```
public func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    let unsortedProducts = response.products
    let products = unsortedProducts.sort{($0.price.compare($1.price) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending)}
    for p in products {
        print("Found product: \(p.productIdentifier) \(p.localizedTitle) \(p.price.floatValue)")
    } ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3, without the need for `self` variables.  Worked for me like a charm to sort by price from low to high:

```
let validProducts = response.products
var productsArray = [SKProduct]()
for i in 0 ..< validProducts.count {
    let product = validProducts[i]
    productsArray.append(product)
}
productsArray.sort{(Double(truncating: $0?.price) < Double(truncating: $1?.price))}
```

**EDIT:** Updated for Swift 5.

Answer (score 0):

In swift

```
 var validProducts = response.products
        for var i = 0; i < validProducts.count; i++
        {
            self.product = validProducts[i] as? SKProduct
            self.productsArray.append(product!)
            println(product!.localizedTitle)
            println(product!.localizedDescription)
            println(product!.price)


        }
        self.productsArray.sort{($0.price < $1.price)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.products = products!.sorted(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
            return item1.price.doubleValue < item2.price.doubleValue
        })
```