# How to sort SKProduct array by price value

Tags: ios, nsarray, in-app-purchase, sorting, storekit

I am trying to sort the array of SKProduct I received from Apple Server after sending the list of product id.

I want to sort just by using the following:

```
NSSortDescriptor *lowestPriceToHighest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self.price" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedProducts = [products sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lowestPriceToHighest]];
```

but i got the error message: `Unable to access variable "lowestPriceToHighest"`
Is my sort descriptor defined wrongly?

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4:

```
products.sort(by: { (p0, p1) -> Bool in
    return p0.price.floatValue < p1.price.floatValue
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to remove "self"

```
NSSortDescriptor *lowestPriceToHighest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"price" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortedProducts = [products sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lowestPriceToHighest]];
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have `var products: [SKProduct]` you can do:

```
products.sortInPlace {
    return Float($0.price) < Float($1.price)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSArray *products = [response.products sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
        NSDecimalNumber *first = [(SKProduct*)a price];
        NSDecimalNumber *second = [(SKProduct*)b price];
        return [first compare:second];
    }];
```

from this answer:

[how to sort products by price In App Purchases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074129/how-to-sort-products-by-price-in-app-purchases)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor  *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"_strPrice"
                                                 ascending:sortFlag selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)] ;
```

Try with this selector